# How to use functions parameters dynamically for CSS properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, function, parameters

I've translated some CSS code into plain JavaScript. And now i am trying to make the code a function for ease of use, but it isn't working. I know I've got it wrong, how can I make it work?

This is the CSS code

```
#container_show_chat {display: none;};
#container_chat {background-image: url('the url');};
```

In Javascript it translates to:

```
var a = document.getElementById("container_show_chat");
a.style.display = "none";
var b = document.getElementById("container_chat");
b.style.backgroundImage = "url('the url')";
```

Now what I am trying to do is, convert it into a function such that whenever i call the function I just have to add the property for the display and the url for the background image in the function call. For example:

```
function Practice(display, image) {
var a = document.getElementById("container_show_chat");
a.style.display;
var b = document.getElementById("container_chat");
b.style.backgroundImage;
};
Practice("none", "the url");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The exact same was as you were.  Exception `"none"` is replaced with `display` and likewise for the backgroundImage.  This is a simple case of literal values replaced with variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the parameters to the elements as well. Like

```
function Practice(display, image) {
  var a = document.getElementById("container_show_chat");
  a.style.display = display;
  var b = document.getElementById("container_chat");
  b.style.backgroundImage = image;
};

Practice("none", "the url");
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps very well

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a more reusable function. Hope it helps:

```html
    <div id="container_show_chat">Hello world</div>

    <script>

        function setStyleInNode(nodeSelector, styleType, value) {
            var node = document.querySelector(nodeSelector);
            node.style[styleType] = value;
        };

        setStyleInNode("#container_show_chat", 'background', 'red');

    </script>
```